# Implementation for media and file uploading

Tags: typescript, react-native, file-upload, asyncfileupload

I want to make an implementation using react native and typescript, for the user to have the option to browse and upload files/media, also to take a photo with camera and upload it. Do you guys suggest and libraries for this implementation? If yes any idea how to do it. I have made some research but I am confused on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used two libraries that worked well for my implementation.
expo-document-picker: ~10.3.0,  expo-image-picker": "~13.3.1 - for image picker and launching camera.

Hope this helps somebody else